# API call return 404 error in client form

Tags: ajax, forms, mobile

I have a form on the client that makes a call to an api. If i put the url to api in the form action like this, it works :

The above is not a viable solution as the client is a mobile phone. However, if I put this in an ajax call, the code returns 404 - Bad request. My ajax code is as follows:

```
$('#registration-form').on('submit',function(event) {
    // get the form data
    // there are many ways to get this data using jQuery (you can use the class or id also)
    var formData = {
        'name'  : $('input[name=name]').val(),
        'email' : $('input[name=email]').val(),
        'password' : $('input[name=password]').val()
    };
    // process the form
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
        url  : 'http://localhost:8080/thepostapi/v1/register', // the url where we want to POST
        data : JSON.stringify(formData), // our data object        
                    contentType: "application/json",
        dataType : 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
                    success : function(response){ 
                        if(!response.error){ 
                            //Success
                            alert('data retrieved');
                        }else{ 
                            alert(response.message);
                        }
                    },
                    error :function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert("Error '" + jqXhr.status + "' (textStatus: '" + textStatus + "', errorThrown: '" + errorThrown + "')");

                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        $('#dvLoading').fadeOut(100);
                    }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Am i missing something here??

Comment: 404 is not Bad Request, it is Resource Not Found. Check if localhost:8080 is up and accessible.

Comment: This looks like cross domain issue. Browser will not allow to call domains other then domain from where the request origins.

Comment: @Subir Kumar Sao, so how are apis able to processes requests from various clients, because surely if the client is a mobile device it will not be on the same domain

Comment: @TJ the localhost:8080 is running, if I run requests using Chrome's advanced rest client extension , the results are returned fine.

Comment: JSONP , You can also set CORS settings in your server.  Header set example `Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" `

Comment: @MunyaradziNyikavaranda is it accessible from the mobile client? What exactly is the client? A web page? An app?

Comment: @SubirKumarSao, would it be possible for me to send you my api code?

Comment: @TJ the client will be a mobile app, but for now I am using my browser to simulate the client

Comment: and you get a 404 from what? If you get a 404 from the app, check if the app is allowed to access localhost urls.